# Patching JBoss EAP 6.4 fails

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-eap-6

I'm trying to patch my jboss eap 6.4 with the following command:

```
jboss-cli.bat "patch apply jboss-eap-6.4.6-patch.zip 
--preserve=[org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-atom-   
provider:main,org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-cdi:main, 
org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider.main,
org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider:main,
org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxb-provider:main, 
org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs:main,
org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jettison-provider:main, 
org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jsapi:main, 
org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-multipart-provider:main, 
org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-yaml-provider:main]"
```

But it fails with the below error:

```
Use the --override-all, --override=[] or --preserve=[] arguments in order to resolve the conflict.
```

According to https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.2/html/Installation_Guide/sect-Install_Patches_in_Zip_Form.html I should use:

```
--preserve=path(,path)</code>
```

Am I maybe interpreting the line above incorrectly?

Comment: if you're using eap, presumably with a support subscription, wouldn't opening a ticket be fastest approach to resolve this? AFAIK they're quite fast in resolving these.

Comment: Did you happen to modify this module from the base 6.4.0 version by any chance? I am trying to understand why are you needing to add the -preserve flag? What was the original conflict with the patch command? Could you please paste the console output from that attempt?

Comment: The -preserve flag is needed I'm afraid because the company I work for insists on changing versions of some modules manually instead of using the bundled ones.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot patch a 6.2 version to 6.4.6 with the patch command. Patch command is intended for cumulative patching, not upgrading from 6.2 to 6.4. You will need to first install the base JBoss EAP 6.4.0 and then apply the CP06 patch. If the patching is successful, then restart your JBoss instance and you should see a log message that indicates the version of JBoss EAP 6.4.6.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It was a typo I'm afraid. I'm actually trying to patch version 6.4.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the "[]" around the list? The quote you specified about the syntax does not include the brackets:

`--preserve=path(,path)`